# Tool to resize and compress at least 2 images at once

Tags: windows, images

I am looking for Windows software, most desirably free or open source, but not necessarily, that will let me do the following actions at the same time, to more than 2 image files (i.e. to several files at once):

1. Resize the images (say from 1024x768 px to 800x600 px).
2. Compress the images.

I'd prefer a tool with a GUI.

Comment: Is a command-line tool OK?

Comment: Okay but will prefer GUI in this case.

Comment: @benos What image file formats are you interested in?

Comment: No special demands so all common (png, jpg, and all others common along side them).

Comment: Well, maybe someone here might want to develop such a tool. It can be good for SEOers\  Optimizers, who need to do exactly these tasks with almost any image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do this with [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/).

Try `Batch Conversion/Rename...` from the `File` menu as explained in [this forum](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/50519/simple-batch-conversion-using-irfanview/).

**Making Transparencies**

Yes you can do this, too.

Follow this Steps:

- Select as "Output format" **PNG**
- Go to "Options" and select there
- Save Transparent Color
- Save Transparency as Alpha Challe

After that you can decide if you want to click on every Picture to select the color or you can use the Option

- Use main windows color for transparency

[image: Screenshot Options]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot so that we get an idea of how it solves the problem? Thanks! Please also read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality cheers!

Comment: Irfanview is fantastic - note that it's free for personal use only, though.

Comment: @WayneWerner: yeah, and there seems to be no way for companies to buy it...

Comment: Informing those who answered, I've updated the question with an extra feature needed. Can the tool you offered supply that?

Comment: @benos i have updated my answer with informations to your new question

Comment: I removed the demand for adding alpha channel and removing white/other background from the image as I moved it to a separate request: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/add-alpha-channel-and-remove-backround-for-more-than-2-images-at-once-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment41178_28776

Answer (score 9):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is designed for this purpose.

> ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, compose, or convert
>   bitmap images. It can read and write images in a variety of formats
>   (over 200) including PNG, JPEG, JPEG-2000, GIF, TIFF, DPX, EXR, WebP,
>   Postscript, PDF, and SVG. Use ImageMagick to resize, flip, mirror,
>   rotate, distort, shear and transform images, adjust image colors,
>   apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses
>   and Bézier curves.

Example of resizing/compressing 2 images at once:

```
convert -resize 64x64 -quality 85% in1.png out1.jpg & convert -resize 64x64 -quality 85% in2.png out2.jpg
```

Comment: That are 2 commands, so it isn't at once...

Comment: @wb9688: The two command are actually run in parallel, they would run one after the other if it were a `;`. Running in parallel is what you want, right?

Comment: @wb9688: Command line utilities is easily combined with helps of shell commands

Comment: I'm not sure. I know no GUI realizations. But is possible that someone somehow implemented GUI for IM (e.g. some file manager and likes) and I prefer not to accuse this broad but unknown to me auditory. So effectively no.

Comment: I removed the demand for adding alpha channel and removing white/other background from the image as I moved it to a separate request: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/add-alpha-channel-and-remove-backround-for-more-than-2-images-at-once-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment41178_28776

Comment: @wb9688 can you write a command that will do it for all images in a folder but NOT recursively ?

Answer (score 2):

Try Fast Stone Image viewer. I am using it for years - fast and powerful. In Tools - Batch convert you can set following settings for jpeg format

- Quality 1-10 (or use existing from the file)
- Photometric
- Color Subsampling
- Smoothing
- Optimise Huffman Table
- Progressive
- Keep EXIF Data

Also you can do much more in **single pass** in Advanced Options, like resize the larger edge to XXX pixels, put watermark in middle, crop center,...

Comment: Informing those who answered, I've updated the question with an extra feature needed. Can the tool you offered supply that?

Comment: Nope, it can't deal with the added requirements. In this case I would try to use the Photoshop - File - Automate - Batch functionality but seems that @f4bi4n answer is easier.

Answer (score 1):

[xnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) is another great media browser, viewer and converter. cross-platform and compatible with more than 500 formats.

in order to resize and compress multiple images with this software, you can select desired images and select `Tools > Batch Convert` or press `ctrl+U`. in the tab `actions` you can specify what transformations you would like done on the files.

Comment: Please show how to transform 2 images at once with that tool, either screenshots, or command-line, thanks! Also please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

Comment: You can batch process images in the `Tool` menu or using ^u. Resizing is one of many transformations that are applicable. Also can save recurring transformations to quickly reuse them rather than setting them up every time.

Comment: I removed the demand for adding alpha channel and removing white/other background from the image as I moved it to a separate request: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/add-alpha-channel-and-remove-backround-for-more-than-2-images-at-once-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment41178_28776

Answer (score 1):

Originally a Power Toy for XP, I always use [Image Resizer for Windows](https://imageresizer.codeplex.com) - it has shell integration as well, so it's as simple as right-clicking on the image you want to resize, or set of images and resizing. It will allow you to resize the original or create new versions.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it doesn't do compression, only resizing (`Advanced settings...` -> `Coming soon... Select JPEG quality level`).

Comment: I removed the demand for adding alpha channel and removing white/other background from the image as I moved it to a separate request: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/add-alpha-channel-and-remove-backround-for-more-than-2-images-at-once-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment41178_28776

Answer (score 1):

ComicRack, CbxConverter (WebP output only) - they are intended to convert comic books (i.e. zip or rar archives with images inside), but this format makes sense if you have multiple small files.

Comment: No. With this requirement I would point to GIMP.

Comment: I removed the demand for adding alpha channel and removing white/other background from the image as I moved it to a separate request: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/add-alpha-channel-and-remove-backround-for-more-than-2-images-at-once-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment41178_28776