# Add alpha channel and remove background for more than 2 images at once in Windows

Tags: windows, image-processing

I look for a tool, most desirably open source or Free software, that can run on Windows 10 and has a GUI, that can take X number of images (definitely more than 5) and just add Alpha channel to all these images, and delete their (say White) background, as well as changing their extension to *.png* so that the change could surely take effect.

AFAIK, the program GIMP can do it per one image, so, I need something that can, most probably dedicated for this cause.

Comment: You could always add a script to GIMP so as to be able to do in to each image quickly or you could use Image Magick to do it without the command line.

Comment: Not tried it myself, but as you mention Gimp: you know it has a [batch mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) as well?

Comment: If you would like, you could publish a question & answer with an explanation here or in Super User here in StackExchange. I will be glad to accept & Thumb up if it worked to me since I also use GIMP. I won't be the only 1 to thumb up I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/).

Try `Batch Conversion/Rename...` from the `File` menu as explained in [this forum](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/50519/simple-batch-conversion-using-irfanview/).

An then use this for the transparencies:

- Select as "Output format" **PNG**
- Go to "Options" and select there
- Save Transparent Color
- Save Transparency as Alpha Challe

After that you can decide if you want to click on every Picture to select the color or you can use the Option

- Use main windows color for transparency

[image: Screenshot Options]

Comment: Have you tried "Use main windows color for transparency" ?

Comment: I was confused, I couldn't check it when unchecked save transparent color, now it's fine thanks.